# Asp.net MVC VS ASP.net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am starting a new project in VB /.Net Framework 2.0 for a company corporate website with data driven forms. So should I go further with Asp.net MVC or Asp.Net web forms and WHY ???  We are not ready for Ajax now but later.
And also we have DevExpress components.

Comment: this been done to death http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webforms+vs+mvc have a read of some of those questions and see if you can decide for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I see ASP.NET MVC as next generation in that it is an evolution - trying to be a better programming environment, as software development for web apps asks for something more testable.

It is a huge beast. Decide based on features whether you need it. MVC has less documentation and is a lot harder to master thanks to a less RAD approach, but it seems that once you are in, it will be quite a better experience. If you have a web application (like stackoverflow.com) then it may be a good approach.

DevExpress components - have fun... throwing them away. Like most ASP.NET components they will not work or only work very partially. Totally different approach.e

Comment: I like your first sentence, it's true, it depends on how you perceive the term "next generation", and you're right.  MVC architectures whilst very old are a new approach to the web.  Is it the "next generation" in web development? Well yes, especially with the amount of frameworks cropping up i.e. RoR, ASP.NET MVC, MonoRail and all the Java frameworks too. +1

Comment: MVC is only 'a new approach to the web' if you've only worked ASP based projects before - it is very well established in the Java world (And probably other languages too)

Comment: No, it is also the next step in ASP.NET - the atempt to bring MVC to ASP.NET. Whether it is in use in other languages is irrelevant - it is an evolutionary step in some ways for ASP.NET, which is all I indicated. I learn it at the moment, and I like it a lot from a programmer point of view.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC is not "next generation" ASP.Net. It's an alternative approach to design that can be more beneficial depending on the kind of project you're working with. Without more information about the particular type of project you're working on no one can give you any informed recommendations.